# how to apply transition effects when switching from light mode to dark in tailwind 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

So I'm building a small-ish project with tailwindCSS and thought of implementing the dark mode. I made a button and mapped it to put the `dark` class in the html tag. After testing for a bit, I realized that switching looked kind of odd because it is happening instantaneously. Is there a way to apply a transition duration or timing function to this change?

Here's the basic logic of how I'm handling the change (also I'm using vue):

```js
<template>
  <!-- <span class="material-icons">&#xE51C;&#xE518;</span> -->
  <input @click="darkClassToggle" id="toggle" class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "darkModeToggle",
  methods: {
    darkClassToggle() {
      const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
      const html = document.firstElementChild;
      if (toggle.checked) {
        html.classList.remove("dark");
      } else {
        html.classList.add("dark");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: On any element you want a transition to happen on just add the classes `transition` (or any other transition class) and `duration-300` (or your preferred speed) it will apply for theme changes as well since all that is changing usually with dark mode is colors. If however you have other things transitioning as well you'll need to enable them in your tailwind config file.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out and got it working. I was applying transition to html tag instead of body where I had declared the dark theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding to the suggestion above, rather than append `transition` and `duration-300` to every tag with a `dark:` variant, simply add it globally to your CSS files (I'm assuming that's `index.css`) and It will affect every element like so

```css
body * {
    @apply transition-colors duration-200;
}
```

This will target every descendant of `body` and apply those tailwind classes you want on them automatically.

I hope this helps

Comment: This worked method works for me, vey nice

Comment: This was great to test and debug, but for some reason it was causing me so many issues on elements where there were already transition classes applied on hover, including several animations running on series instead of parallel. So in my experience: **better apply transitions more selectively**

Comment: Note that this causes the page to transition every time you navigate aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `transition-colors duration-1000` classes to body like this:

```
<body class="transition-colors duration-1000">
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, because transition effects are not automatically cascaded down to child elements. This would only work if the color is set in the body element and then the child elements inherit the color. But the transition class itself is not inherited